# Android - by clicking instead of going forward is back to the previous page

Tags: java, android

I use Android Studio, created four new activity each button. I try every button leads to the next page.
After I attach all the buttons I run the app and it really works.
When I press the button on the first page it takes me to the second page, but when I press the button on the second page to go to the third, it takes me back to the first page.

first activity:

```
 package liranbenzino.kids;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View viewBtnClick) {
            // link to class
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }});
}}
```

second activity:

```
package liranbenzino.kids;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View viewBtnClick1) {
            // link to class
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }});
}
}
```

thied activity:

```
package liranbenzino.kids;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View viewBtnClick) {
            // link to class
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main3Activity.this,Main4Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }});
}
}
```

four activity:

```
package liranbenzino.kids;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);


    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View viewBtnClick) {
            Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this,"NAME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}});
}}
```

AndroidMenifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="liranbenzino.kids">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Main4Activity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

thank'S

Comment: what is your question, what do you want?

Comment: can i see your AndroidMenifest.xml their may have some prob..

Comment: it seems ok, something is missing in any other place, may be you set in menifest single instance true something like

Comment: i add  AndroidMenifest.xml to edit

Comment: 07-17 14:28:26.425 28660-28660/liranbenzino.kids W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Answer (score 0):

### Your code is ok

How your decide that you back to firstPage when your click 2nd activity button. your code is ok.. use label in each page. then try ...

May be your some button label is same and you become confuse in which page you are in..

You can change your button label as First_Page_Button,Second_Page_Button,Third_Page_Button etc to decide in which page you are...

Comment: i dont understand what the problem

Comment: do you use any label to identify in which page you are...may be you button label is same in page1 and page3 so you think u are in page1 after click on 2nd page button...........check it..

Answer (score -1):

in each activity change the INTENT name for example in activity2 change 
Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
to
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
startActivity(intent2);

Comment: Scope/name of variables isn't the problem here.